# SUM MySQL rows of one column and have it group by another

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guys I'm trying to create a query which sums one column and groups the result by another.

Let me show you what I mean by showing my tables!

This is my **tickets** table

[image]

Expect result

[image]

As you can see it groups the column app and issue and then SUMS the time per issue.

Currently I have something like this

```
 SELECT app,issue,sum(time)
 FROM tickets
 GROUP BY issues
 ORDER BY name ASC;
```

However it's not outputting the expected result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also group by app in addition to issues

```
SELECT app,issue,sum(time)
FROM tickets
GROUP BY app,issue
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You only grouped by the issues, don't forget adding the app to the group by also.

This should work for you:

```
SELECT app, 
       issue, 
       Sum(time) 
FROM   tickets 
GROUP  BY app, 
          issues 
ORDER  BY name ASC;
```